# when i can use linearization method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $ x' = f(x) $ be a system of nonlinear differential equation in two variable. Is there any necessary and sufficient condition to use linearization method on it ?

Comment: If the derivative exist in the approximation point, you can use the approximation. The proper question is if the linearization preserves the same behaviour than the original system under the approximation. Or not? Maybe this depends on your required behaviour dotnt you think?

Answer (score 0):

dy/dx + Py = Q
This is the form of linear differential equation where P,Q are functions of only 'x' or constants.
So, first write the given equation in this form and then use the method of integrating factor to solve the linear differential equation.

Comment: I think this do not fully answer the question

Comment: What answer do you expect?

Comment: One involving how the stability of the system is affected by the linearization in the approximating point. What if the approximation is stable and the system is not?

Comment: I don't think I am in this discussion anymore! Sorry but the answer I posted was all I knew and I m not aware of concepts like stability at a point. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No, the answer is already posted :)